# Reset MySQL table data after each session is completed in php

Tags: mysql, php

I am creating a PHP application demo. The users who login can insert, modify and delete data but when they logout the data must be reset to the default data I set before.

The data must reset depending on the session so that multiple users can access the default data at the same time.

Is this possible using MySQL?

**UPDATE 1:**
I have created a stored procedure to create a new db and dump the `default` data, but I am getting an error while using the `USE db_name` in a procedure.

NOTE: I am using phpMyAdmin.

Error: `#1314 USE is not allowed in stored procudures`

Here is the stored procedure i have created with sample data.

```
BEGIN

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dp_demo2` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `dp_demo2`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customers`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `cid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `skype_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zip_code` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `customers`
--

INSERT INTO `customers` (`cid`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `company`, `email`, `phone`, `skype_id`, `address`, `city`, `country`, `zip_code`, `created`) VALUES
(1, 'Julie', 'Penning', 'Apple', 'juli@example.com', '0402011', '@julie', '20-120, Street', 'Calfornia', 'USA', 40192, '2016-07-16 04:05:22'),
(2, 'Karl', 'Max', 'Ham. co.', 'karl@example.com', '9828101', '@max.karl', '20-820, Street', 'New York', 'USA', 82918, '2016-07-16 04:06:57'),
(3, 'Jhon', 'Doe', 'Microsoft', 'jhon@example.com', '892123', '@jhone.doe', '9-21-23, ham street', 'Troy', 'USA', 83082, '2016-07-16 04:08:48');

END
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I am able to create new db and use them, but i got another problem, how can I get dynamic db_name into the stored procedure.

Parameters for the stored procedure is not working for names, but only for the data.

Comment: Can you provide an estimation of how much data we are talking about at the start and how much is written: 1MB, 1GB, 1TB, 1 PB? How many concurrent users will be accessing with separate "views"? How much disk and memory you have available? Do you have restrictions on how much time it must take to reset the data?

Comment: I am having around 6 -8 tables with less than 10 rows per table, about 10 -20  concurrent users will access the db maybe less. I am having around 1GB of memory and there is no restriction on time taken to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup:

1. Take a mysqldump of the 'default' data.
2. Put the output into a Stored Procedure.
3. Modify the stored procedure to also `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` that database.  The database name would be dynamic -- probably the user id, with something prepended to avoid naming conflicts.  Also surround with backtics.

User comes in:

1. perform that stored procedure.

User leaves.  This could be tricky -- what if he stays logged in?  what if some server dies without getting to this code?  Etc.  There may need to be something that runs around periodically to clean up orphaned databases.

1. Drop his database.

Note:  Your question implied that everyone is using the *same* database.  I switched to having everyone use a different database.

Comment: I have created a stored procedure but i am unable to use the `USE` command in the stored procedure to select the DB which has been created.

Comment: Then do the equivalent in PHP.

Comment: But I am unable to pass new db name as a parameter to the stored procedure.

Comment: Pass it to a PHP function, then construct the statements you need to execute.

Comment: I got it working, but everything is done via PHP. I have got another problem, my hosting provider doesn't allow me to create new db from php, any other solution which doesn't involve in creating new db would be helpful.

Comment: Then consider: One database, but table names are constructed by concatenating, say, the user_id and the table name.  Be sure to kept it clean -- 10,000 tables in a single database _may_ have performance problems.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames, I got it working, my demo would only last 10 mins, so at every login it checks for expired demo's and it will delete them, so it is easy to maintain.